# Select from JSON object with colon in key using alasql

Tags: alasql

I have this dataset:

```js
[
  {
    "date": "2020-06-07",
    "data": {
      "publish": true,
      "publish:title": "Hello world from tempo!"
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-06-07",
    "data": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-06-07",
    "data": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-06-07",
    "data": {
      "sleep:start": 9.5,
      "sleep:duration": 10
    }
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-06-06",
    "data": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-06-06",
    "data": null
  }
]
```

I want to select the date and data["sleep:start"] values for each row using Alasql. The documentation suggests using `obj->property->subproperty` for that purpose, so my Alasql query should look a bit like this:

```sql
SELECT date, data->sleep:start FROM ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 6
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and quoting `sleep:start` doesn't either. Is there a way to do what I'm looking for using Alasql?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it works with this: `SELECT date, data->[sleep:duration] FROM ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 6`

ref https://github.com/agershun/alasql/issues/1201#issuecomment-639171925